# angular 4 + WebApi

Tags: angularjs-2.0, asp.net-web-api

Buenas,

Estoy intentando mostrar por la consola del navegador los objetos obtenidos en la peticion get desde angular test.service.ts:

```
   getTestValues_Get() :Observable<Itest []>{
  return this._http.get(this.url)
        .map(response => <Itest[]> response.json());  }
```

la llamada desde el componente test.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {             
         this._TestService.getSettings_Get()
         .subscribe(( test: ITest []) => {
              this.test= test;
             console.log("Array ->:" + this.test)
         });}
```

Desde la WebApi devuelve esto en ValuesController.cs.

```
   [HttpGet]
    public Setting Get()
    {
        using (Entities EntityDB= new Entities())
        {
           return EntityDB.Settings.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.TestId == 1);
        }
    }
```

Al ejecutarlo obtengo este error:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json

Tambien he añadido en WebApiConfig.cs:

```
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.Add(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

¿Alguna idea de donde puede estar el problema?

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

has revisado que esto te devuelva el objeto correcto debugeando?

```
[HttpGet]
public Setting Get()
{
    using (Entities EntityDB= new Entities())
    {
       return EntityDB.Settings.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.TestId == 1);
    }
}
```

si lo que intentas es devolver json por defecto, (recuerda que si no configuras nada la api devuelve el formato que pida el navegador), solo deberia bastar con agregar esta linea.

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```